# Linq - Orderby by ID Value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-order-by

I have the following linq:

```
    objfl  = db.tblFl.First(t => t.sp == id && t.ProgID == sPgm);
```

I like to also order by id but not sure how to do this. I tried a number of different ways but was not successful

Comment: Have you tried `db.tblFl.OrderBy(t => t.sp)`?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense right now - either you want to order by id **or** you want to find items with matching id - both doesn't make sense - which is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested by BrokenGlass, if you want to filter by ProgID, sort by sp and retrieve the first item:

```
db.tblFl.Where(t => t.ProgID == sPgm)
        .OrderBy(t => t.sp)
        .First()
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense - **all** items clearly will have `sp` that matches `id` - so ordering by that doesn't add anything at all.

Comment: @BrokenGlass, you are right, I think the code I added is what the OP is looking for

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
objfl  = db.tblFl.Where(t => t.sp == id && t.ProgID == sPgm).OrderBy(t => t.sp);
```

Comment: Hey am sorry, I have given wrong answer. You people are right. I missed to replace **First** to **Where**.